# Is there any cut of beef that's close to Kobe beef?

Tags: beef, steak

I have had the real thing in Japan and it was fantastic and very expensive. I don't usually eat steak at all. The Kobe beef steak was the first I ate in my entire life. It was very tender and tasty, cooked medium rare. I had it because there was nothing else on the menu I would consider eating.

I live in Canada. I want to know if there is a cut of beef that's available in Canada that's close to Kobe beef quality.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, thank you for the info

Comment: Kobe beef only comes from Japan.  You should be careful to read the country of origin labels.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hello @Huangism and welcome to Seasoned Advice. You may consider domestic wagyu. To get the best, it will still be pricey, but not nearly as much as Kobe. Please see this excerpt from  [Lobel's of New York](http://www.lobels.com/store/wagyuMain_whatis.aspx) .

> You Get What You Pay For
>
> All Wagyu beef is not created equal. In Japan, Kobe beef sells at more than $300 per pound.
> But now Wagyu is starting to be seen in grocery stores and casual-dining restaurants for $30 per pound. This mass-marketed variety of Wagyu will have a marbling score at the low end of the 12-point scale.
> American Wagyu Beef from Lobel's of New York will score 9 points or higher. More expensive than our USDA Prime, our American Wagyu costs a bit more than $100 per pound (depending on the cut). In terms of quality, taste, and texture, Wagyu and Kobe beef are indistinguishable.
> If what you're looking for is best quality Wagyu, you should expect to pay $100 or more per pound.

The linked page has a lot more information and more links to additional info. Although this place is in the US, I linked it because of the information available. Performing anther search, I found that wagyu beef is now available in Canada at Loblaws in
Toronto and also at Costco (various provinces).

Comment: There is a Costco 5 minutes from my house, I will look for it

Comment: I haven't see Wagyu beef at my local costco, but it's definitely available on their website.

Comment: @Huangism I've never looked for it myself, but on the food mailing list where I work it seems like once or twice a year there's a thread with someone saying "hey there's wagyu again, who wants to share some?" so you might just have to keep checking back.

Comment: "Wagyu and Kobe beef are indistinguishable" -- **misleading**. Kobe beef is Wagyu beef from Kobe Prefecture. So is Ohmi, a Wagyu beef from Hyogo Prefecture. Unnamed Wagyu, especially from countries other than Japan, will have a different flavour, texture, aroma, and taste. The grade is important, yes, but that's just the intramuscular fat content. There are many other factors at play.

Answer (score 10):

The problem with you stating Kobe beef is its not a cut of meat. Kobe beef comes from certain cattle raised in Japan. In Canada your best bet will be to find the best quality beef you can. Depending on preference I'd suggest sirloin for a good all rounder, rib eye if you don't mind the extra fat (my favourite cut) or fillet steak if you want the most tender steak you can get. The problem with fillet in my opinion is the lack of fat which ultimately results in lack of flavour plus the price is stupidly high (in England at least)

Comment: For our North American friends fillet = tenderloin.

Comment: Yes I understand that Kobe beef is not a cut which is why I never mentioned it as a cut in my question. I know different cut of beef can taste different, hence the question. So tenderloin then, I wonder how close it is to the taste of Kobe.

Comment: Can't say I've ever been lucky enough to try it but I know the rib eye from our local butcher (some rare breed) is great. If you are looking for flavour I'd recommend trying 'onlet' one day. Slow cooking meat not quick fry steak but without a doubt the tastiest cut. (a quick Google suggests it might be called hanger steak in the USA)

Comment: Actually, you did specifically mention it as a cut in your question, hence his answer. Kobe beef gets it's flavor from the fat marbling. The closest you're going to get to it is Wagyu beef, which has considerably close marbling. There's no way to cut a cow to make it taste like Kobe unless it's raised like Kobe.

Comment: @AtroxMavenia the cut was not applied to the Kobe beef, but to the beef in Canada. I would Imagine the worst cut of Kobe beef is still better than anything we have in NA

Comment: Alright guys no need to argue over semantics that's what the w3 are for. The question was ambiguous hence the confusion. Regardless, you can't try and compare Kobe Chuck steak to Aberdeen Angus fillet, it's just not right. If you had rib eye then the Best comparison will be a high quality local rib eye, the same would apply if you have a Kobe beef Chuck pie... Beef is beef just buy quality. The same rules would apply for **any** meat, Lamb, Turkey even Salmon. Realistically the **Best** person to be asking is your local butcher not some fool in a supermarket.

Comment: @Huangism: It depends. Not everyone likes the high fat content of Kobe beef. I remember one TV chef who went on a trip to Japan to taste the best of the best Kobe and he was very disappointed that the beef was "tasteless". Grass fed, non-kobe beef, especially if it's been aged, has a more mineral, "beefy" taste compared to kobe. And Angus beef has an even more "beefy" flavor.

Comment: @slebetman I don't really know what to think of the fat, I just thought lean meat is better since it's more expensive. But the marble beef steak I had in Japan was definitely the best I have ever had

Comment: As the saying goes 'Fat is flavour', fillet/tenderloin, the most expensive and leanest part of a cow is in my opinion the most tasteless part. Although it is nice to eat once, just to experience what true tenderness feels like (preferably caked in some strong tasting cheese to enhance the flavour). Stood in a butchers shop with a million pounds to spend I'd pick rib eye **every** time... Unfortunately I'm a chef with very little money to spend so I'll go for the onlet/hangersteak.

Answer (score 10):

Do you know what cut of Kobe beef you had in Japan? Assuming budget is not an issue, your best bet will be to find the same cut in a Kobe Style or Wagyu beef. This is available in Canada. Get the same cut as whatever you had in Wagyu beef.

If you have no idea what cut it was, I'd probably start with a ribeye. It's one of the better, more popular cuts (also pricier). For example, [Costco has Kobe Ribeye steaks](http://www.costco.ca/CatalogSearch?storeId=10302&catalogId=11201&langId=-24&refine=&keyword=kobe) generally. Note, they will be ridiculously expensive.

Stepping away from Kobe/Wagyu cows, look for a Prime grade Rib eye from a reputable butcher. What you're looking for is marbling as close to the following as possible:
[image]

Note, you likely won't get that marbling from anything other than a Kobe/Wagyu cow. That said, you can definitely find some good quality beef around Canada. I'd look for a good butcher (not in a grocery store) and start there.

Comment: I don't know the cut but it is very similar to the picture you have. Yes it was very expensive, I only had one meal involving the beef. I actually didn't think it was good beef since there are so much white on it, but obviously I was wrong

Comment: If it looks similar to that, and you're describing it as really tender, it was likely a ribeye. What area of the country are you in?

Comment: I am in Toronto, Ontario

Comment: Then there should be lots of places/butchers that source Wagyu (or at very least Prime Grade). A few listed here: http://forums.redflagdeals.com/wagyu-steak-toronto-695781/ Loblaws, Famu, Pusateri's

Comment: If you're in Toronto, try J-Town. I've gotten Australian wagyu there and it was good

Comment: > I actually didn't think it was good beef since there are so much white on it -- what did you think the white was?

Comment: @Random832 I thought it was fat

Comment: Fat = tasty. :-)

Comment: @Huangism it is fat... but fat is what makes meat taste good, it's why a ribeye tastes better than a flank steak.

Comment: One (significant) note: In the US, "Kobe" and "Wagyu" are often misused, and only a very small amount of actual Kobe beef is exported - the Costco link above for example is a variety of domestic Wagyu in Canada, isn't even pure Wagyu, and has very little to do with Kobe beef.  If it's good, eat it, but it's not Kobe or anything particularly related.

Answer (score 0):

I lived in Tokyo as a US military dependent from 1956-60 and 1963-65. 
Our military newspaper, The "Stars and Stripes" and the Japanese newspaper, "Mainichi News" (printed in English) ran articles referring to Kobe Beef. 
The articles stated the cows received little exercise, were given a daily bottle of beer, and were messaged daily in order to ensure a high fat content well distributed throughout the meat. 
Even back then, the meat was very expensive, but highly prized by beef eating persons. 
This does not answer your question as to availability, but does explain the midcentury publicized reasons why Kobe Beef was/is so expensive.